# NGINX and OpenStack Horizon?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, mod-wsgi, uwsgi, openstack

I recently update our web infrastructure to use NGINX instead of our Apache servers.
Now, I'm also operating an OpenStack Infrastructure and I was wondering if there is a state of the art way to replace Apache/Mod_wsgi with any NGinx/uwsgi architecture or something else.

So if you operate any OpenStack cloud infrastructure using NGINX instead of Apache, any tips and tricks or even PRO/CONS tips would be really appreciate.

Thanks a lot!!

PS: Oh, and by the way, I'm operating an ESSEX Stack over Debian 7.0